# Refreshing token with Pinia and Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I just started working with Vue and I'm not sure how to protect routes on the front.
I created a login ACTION that sends the token to Local Storage and then I want that every time the user tries to access a protected route the router needs to check if the token is still valid.

I think I'm missing this asynchronous request, but I can't solve it. Does anyone have any tips?

```
async refresh(token) {
            let isLogged = false;
            const response = await fetch("XXXXXXXXXX", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Token": `${token}`
                }
            })
            
            if (!response.ok) {
                return isLogged;
            };
            
            isLogged = true;
            
            return isLogged
        }


router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const isLogged = await authStore.refresh(token)
    
    
    if (to.meta.authRequired) {
        if (isLogged) {
            next();
        } else {
            next("/login");
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }


})
```

Comment: As long as I can see, the `refresh` function is not a method of `authStore` - just a regular function. Also, GET requests do not have content type - only their responses have one. And there is no `Token:` HTTP header - usually it is `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx` and `xxx` is the actual JWT token.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm making these requests to a very exotic API, but postman responds correctly. The action works in the Store but when I invoke refresh inside beforeEach it doesn't.

Comment: You don't need an `action` - a pure function will do just fine. Actions usually commit mutation(s) - but there is no such need in your case. You may want to run the `beforeEach` hook step by step in DevTools to inspect the token and see the API response.

Comment: I understood. I moved the fetch into beforeEach, but the application doesn't even open now. =(
https://postimg.cc/DJ3Yv8zF

Comment: You don't need to fetch on public pages (that do not require authentication).

Comment: The print code above works, I had changed the import of the routes and confused. It became much simpler and more correct to run the fetch inside the asynchronous beforeEach. Thank you for your help!